# How can I change variables, if the variables I want to change to are not directly stated in the term?

Tags: equation-solving, replacement, semantic-matching

So I don't mean something like this

```
f[x_] = x^2
f[x] /. x^2 -> y
```

But what I mean is something like this:

[image]

where the variables I want to change to are defined like that:

```
u = (x + y * σ)/(1+σ)
```

[image]

```
v = z
```

[image]

```
w = (-x + y)/(1+σ)
```

[image]

The problem here is that something like

```
(x*z*σ)/(-1-σ) /. (x + y * σ)/(1+σ) -> u /. z -> v /. (-x + y)/(1+σ) -> w
```

doesn't work at all.

So what would the proper way to do it be here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
rule = First@
  Solve[{u == (x + y*σ)/(1 + σ), v == z, 
    w == (-x + y)/(1 + σ)}, {x, y, z}]
```

> {x -> u - w σ, y -> u + w, z -> v}

```
(x z σ)/(-1 - σ) /. rule
```

$$\frac{\sigma  v (u-\sigma  w)}{-\sigma -1}$$

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this will help:

```
expr = (x  z \[Sigma])/(1 + \[Sigma])

solW = Solve[w == (-x + y)/(1 + \[Sigma]), \[Sigma]]

Simplify[expr /. solW]

Simplify[Simplify[expr /. solW]][[1]] /. z -> v
```

This doesn't give the answer you put in, perhaps because I don't see what v and z are doing in your code.

Your attempts to do this "(x + y * σ)/(1+σ) ->"  make sense, that expression may not be internally represented. To check, use FullForm to see what can be matched.